# Scala play framework - completely offline environment

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

Any idea if it's possible to use the Play framework, or akka, within a completely offline, non-internet connected environment?  I tried running, and it's connecting to maven central, etc...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you have all the dependencies you need for a successful build then you can do the following to stop the update check etc:

In plugins.sbt :

```
offline := true
```

Comment: Awesome, so if I download the offline distribution, I should be good to go (in theory, and assuming all dependencies I need are in the dist)

Comment: Maybe you can zip/tar the `~/.m2` and  `~/.ivy2` directories from a connected system, and then replicate in the offline one. I haven't tried this, though. Effectively you should get a functional mirror of the packages needed in your project.

Comment: @Cj Burner - in theory yes but I didn't check it. I did use this successfully whilst offline but I had all the dependencies I need up-to-date. A soon as you up the version of 1 dependency though you usually need a connection to maven central because even if you have that jar locally there are usually some transitive dependencies that need upping too.

Comment: It got pretty close to deploying, although I got errors where the app is trying to connect to aws.amazon.com and some other external websites, even with the offinline : = true.  I`ll keep plugging away.  I get the play activator splash page but with no data.  It's just a full screen picture.  Close, but no cigar as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have Internet connection whenever you *update* your Play project such that the built tool (sbt/play/activator) can download all dependencies for the first time.

Since Play 2.3, dependencies/libraries locally go to ~/.ivy2/local and the cache of downloaded dependencies/libraries is under ~/.ivy2/cache.

Play 2.3 (and above) uses the default ivy cache and repository, in the .ivy2 folder in the users home directory. When you *update* (and hence *compile* or *run*) a Play 2.3.x project, the dependencies go to ~/.ivy2/cache.